# Display Timer letter by letter iphone

Tags: iphone, label

Want i wanna do is to display a label letter by letter like in some games we can find on the app store, but i have no idea on how to do this. May be using a timer ? but how can i tell my label to add only one letter from a string ? ?

Thanks to all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work

```
UILabel* label; //Your label
NSString* myLongString; //Your string
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index > [myLongString length] ; index ++) {
    NSString* subString = [myLongString substringToIndex:index]; //The part you want to show;
    [label performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:subString afterDelay:index];
}
```

Basically, you're just setting the text to a part of your string after a certain delay.

Comment: there is small correction  index<=[myLongString length] otherwise it wont comes into the loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer and append a letter to the label's text, i.e.

```
yourLabel.text = @"H";
```

then

```
yourLabel.text = @"He";
```

then

```
yourLabel.text = @"Hel";
```

then

```
yourLabel.text = @"Hell";
```

then

```
yourLabel.text = @"Hello";
```

You might just want to have a look at delayed messaging with the performSelector: family instead of NSTimer.

Comment: yea but my text is quite long, so i would like use another way. But thanks i'll think about it.

Comment: If you want to use a label (i.e. no custom UIView), then I can think of no different way. Of course you will get the strings you assign more dynamically as a substring from the complete string.

Comment: o really. You would use an custom view to make this ? ?

Comment: i have seen your apps nice job ! is the chess one acailable in french ? ?

Comment: If just needing some text and UILabel could present it the way I want it, I'd go with UILabel. Things will be different if you want to spice it up in different colors etc. Chess apps are in English and German only at the moment.

Comment: :) ok thanks i've think about setting the length of the string hold by the label, but i can't change the length of the string xcode tells me no readonly or setter sets i don't understand.